# Linux screen/java cli issue

Tags: linux, command-line, display, java

I don't know how to properly label this, so if this is a known problem, I'd be glad to be pointed in that direction.

This error could be from java or screen - it probably occurs when I make a screen command, however. JVM is running in the foreground inside of the screen, and outputs to the screen both before and after the issue appears.

The issue is, sometimes after detaching the screen, when reattaching it again, the cursor/focus is somehow placed on the bash prompt "underneath" the java process, and not in the java prompt. As such, any commands I put into the prompt, simply "vanish" from the screen. JVM still prints new output to the screen, it just doesn't register any commands from the terminal.

When stopping the java process, the "lost" commands have been picked up by bash, (fortunately) with a

```
-bash: list: command not found
```

Anyone have any ideas? The screen man page didn't give me anything obvious, and I don't have the knowledge of java/jvm to know what to type to get control of the program again.

Edit: I'm using Oracle Java 1.7.0_51

Comment: Sounds like your Java process isn't reading your buffered input, and it's read by bash after the Java process exits.

Comment: Is there anything that can be done to make it resume listening for terminal input?

Comment: Well, what is this Java process exactly? Are you sure it's supposed to be taking input?

Comment: It's minecraft, and it should listen for input